# Can you assign a 4d String array to SQLite in Android studio?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

I am making a software that generates a meal plan. The contents are stored in a 4d String array named `mealplan[7][6][10][10]`. I want the String array to be the database name(`mealplan`). The 1st index [7] represents the `days`(Sunday-Saturday) which I want to be the table names inside `mealplan`. The second index [6] represents `meals` `{"Breakfast", "AM Snack", "Lunch", "PM Snack", "Dinner", "MN snack"}` which should be table names as well inside `days`. These 1st two indexes are going to be displayed as listviews respectively in the software. The remaining two indexes should now be table rows and columns that will be displayed as a tablelayout stored inside `meals`. My problem is can you store a table(`meals`) which contains rows and columns inside another table(`days`) stored in a database named(`mealplan`)? Here's a short illustration of what I need `String mealplan(database)[days(table)][meals(table)][rows][columns]`

Comment: You should create classes.

Comment: What is the meaning of the rows and columns?